# lftp - mirror and wildcards

Tags: ftp, sftp, mirroring, wildcards

Is there anyway to use wildcards ("*") when using mirror command? I know there is a mget command, which is simply the same as get, but one can use wildcards with it. Is there something equivelant to mirror command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `--include-glob=<wildcard>` switch (or `-I <wildcard>`).

There are also other options. See the [`lftp` man page](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html).

Comment: Thank you for that! I don't how did I missed it when reading manpage.